# почему не работает SELECT LIKE %% в MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

в таблице есть поле типа TEXT в него пишутся данные формата json. например есть запись с таким значением:

```
,"\/nomera\/nomer-ekonom-1\/","\/nomera\/nomer-ekonom-2\/","\/nomera\/nomer-ekonom-3\/",
```

пробую получить ее, используя такой запрос:

```
SELECT  * FROM `table` WHERE `url` LIKE "%\/nomera/\/nomer-ekonom-2\/%";
```

по ничего не находится... скорей всего тут что-то с экранированием, но я не могу понять что...
Просьба подсказать, в чем ошибка.

Comment: *данные формата json. например есть запись с таким значением* Это не JSON, а чёрт те что... *пробую получить ее, используя такой запрос* У MySQL есть пачка JSON-функций, в том числе и функции поиска заданных значений. PS. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в Вашем примере найдется что-нибудь по запросу

```
SELECT  * FROM `table` WHERE `url` LIKE "%\/nomera%\/nomer-ekonom-2\/%";
```